# How to multiply multi-dimensional arrays/matrices in Julia

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia, matrix-multiplication

Multiplying two multi-dimensional arrays, say, a 1-dimensional with a 3-dimensional array:

```
[1 2] * reshape(1:8,2,2,2)
```

gives me the error message:

```
LoadError: MethodError: `*` has no method matching *(::Array{Int64,2}, ::Array{Int64,3})
Closest candidates are:
  *(::Any, ::Any, !Matched::Any, !Matched::Any...)
  *{TA,TB}(::Union{DenseArray{TA,1},DenseArray{TA,2},SubArray{TA,1,A<:DenseArray{T,N},I<:Tuple{Vararg{Union{Colon,Int64,Range{Int64}}}},LD},SubArray{TA,2,A<:DenseArray{T,N},I<:Tuple{Vararg{Union{Colon,Int64,Range{Int64}}}},LD}}, !Matched::Base.LinAlg.AbstractTriangular{TB,S<:AbstractArray{T,2}})
  *{TA,TQ,N}(::Union{DenseArray{TA,N},SubArray{TA,N,A<:DenseArray{T,N},I<:Tuple{Vararg{Union{Colon,Int64,Range{Int64}}}},LD}}, !Matched::Union{Base.LinAlg.QRCompactWYQ{TQ,M<:AbstractArray{T,2}},Base.LinAlg.QRPackedQ{TQ,S<:AbstractArray{T,2}}})
  ...
while loading In[167], in expression starting on line 1

 in Ac_mul_B at operators.jl:157
```

using the math definition of multi-dimensional matrix algebra for a (1 by 2) * (2 by 2 by 2) multiplication of matrices/arrays.

A somewhat more general example can be A*B = C meaning sum_k A_{i,j,k} B_{k,l,m} = C_{i,j,l,m}, where A is a 3-index matrix, or tensor if you like, B is a 3-index one, and the resulting C is a four index matrix/tensor, but, in general, there can be any number of dimensions and a dimension can have any size (within reason). See more info on the definition of a [matrix product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#General_definition_of_the_matrix_product) or [tensor contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction).

What is the right syntax of this multiplication in Julia?

Comment: use `.*` instead of `*`

Comment: What do you mean with "math definition of multi-dimensional matrix algebra". Tensor product?  The tensor product between matrices is obtained by ``kron``. Or the elementwise product ``.*``?

Comment: @mschauer To make it general enough to understand, by A*B = C I mean sum_k A_{i,j,k} B_{k,l,m} = C_{i,j,l,m}, where A is a 3-index matrix, or tensor if you like, B is a 3-index one, and the resulting C is a four index matrix/tensor. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#General_definition_of_the_matrix_product for a definition of a matrix product. My above definition is just a generalization for n-dimensional matrices for n>2. If you are familiar with Matlab, this operation is done by `*` there.

Comment: That is a [tensor contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction).

Comment: @Vincent Zoonekynd Exactly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reshape` to convert the multi-dimensional arrays into matrices,
multiply them, and convert the result back to a multi-dimensional array.

```
A = [1 2]
B = reshape(1:8,2,2,2)
reshape( reshape(A,2,1)' * reshape(B,2,4), 2, 2 )
```

(In this example, since `A` is already a matrix, there is actually no need to reshape it.)

Comment: Is this the fastest way to do it? That is, the compiler will be smart enough that the `reshape` ops are zero-cost?

Comment: `reshape` should be very cheap. https://github.com/JuliaMath/TensorCore.jl has a version of this wrapped up neatly (and careful about adjoint vectors etc.), with which you can just write `A ⊡ B`.

Answer (score 1):

Matrices multiplication: use *

Matrices element-wise multiplication: use .*

If you want to multiply two matrices `A*B`, the size of both must much: e.g.
size of A (`a1,a2`),
size of B (`b1, b2`); 
in order to make the multiplication feasible `a2` must be the same as `b1`

In your case:

```
julia> A=[1 2]
1x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2

julia> size(A) #remember that size(A') is (2,1)
(1,2)

julia> B=reshape(1:8,2,2,2)
2x2x2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  3
 2  4

[:, :, 2] =
 5  7
 6  8

julia> size(B)
(2,2,2)

julia> size(B[:,:,1])
(2,2)   

julia> A*B[:,:,1]
1x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 5  11

julia> A*B[:,:,2]
1x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 17  23
```

Edit: Multiplication in "one shot" (separated for clarity):

```
julia> A*B[:,:,1]
1x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 5  11

julia> A*B[:,:,2]
1x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 17  23

julia> C=A*B[:,:]
1x4 Array{Int64,2}:
 5  11  17  23

julia> size(C)
(1,4)

julia> D1 = reshape(C, 2,2)
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
  5  17
 11  23

julia> D2 = reshape(C, 2,2)'
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
  5  11
 17  23
```

Truly in one shot:

```
julia> D = reshape(A*B[:,:], 2,2)
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
  5  17
 11  23
```

Comment: Yes, those are the numbers I expect for the two layers of A*B , but I don't see how to do this multiplication 'in one shot' like A*B instead of doing A*B[:,:,1] and A*B[:,:,2].

Comment: I've updated the answer. To be honest it is hard to give you an answer since I do not understand the whole problem :)

Comment: See my comment after the question for a precise definition :)

Comment: If you say so, I'm glad :)

Comment: Well, at least D1 is the solution for this particular example. But if the size of the matrices are not known beforehand, say, `A` is `m1` by `m2` and `B` is an `n1` by `n2` by `n3` matrix, where `m1=n1` then you need to introduce more noise using the size of the matrices: `A = [1 2]
B = reshape(1:12,2,2,3)
reshape(A*B[:,:],size(B,2),size(B,3))`. But there may be a way of redefining the `*` operator for such matrix operations.