# Batch matrix multiplication in Julia

Tags: numpy, julia, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to multiply N-dimensional (N>=3) arrays in Julia as batches of matrices, i.e. perform matrix multiplication along the last two dimensions, keeping the other dimensions intact.

For example, if `x` has dimensions `(d1,d2,4,3)` and `y` has dimensions `(d1,d2,3,2)`, the result of the multiplication should have `(d1,d2,4,2)`, i.e. a batch of matrix multiplications should be performed.

This is exactly what happens in Python's [`numpy.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html):

> If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly.

```py
np.matmul(randn(10,10,4,3), randn(10,10,3,2)).shape
(10, 10, 4, 2)
```

**Is there a way to reproduce the behaviour of `numpy.matmul` in Julia?**

I hoped `.*` would work, but:

```
julia> randn(10,10,4,3) .* randn(10,10,3,2)
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size")
Stacktrace:
 [1] _bcs1 at ./broadcast.jl:485 [inlined]
 [2] _bcs at ./broadcast.jl:479 [inlined] (repeats 3 times)
 [3] broadcast_shape at ./broadcast.jl:473 [inlined]
 [4] combine_axes at ./broadcast.jl:468 [inlined]
 [5] instantiate at ./broadcast.jl:256 [inlined]
 [6] materialize(::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Base.Broadcast.DefaultArrayStyle{4},Nothing,typeof(*),Tuple{Array{Float64,4},Array{Float64,4}}}) at ./broadcast.jl:798
 [7] top-level scope at REPL[80]:1
```

I understand a list comprehension might work in 3-D, but this would get really messy in higher dimensions. Is the best solution to reshape (or view) all but the last 2 dimensions, use a list comprehension, and reshape it back? Or is there a better way?

P.S. The closest thing I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685517/how-to-multiply-multi-dimensional-arrays-matrices-in-julia), but it's not quite the same. New to Julia, so might be missing something obvious to Julia users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any such functionality, but there may well be in some package. I think that in Julia it's more natural to organize the data as arrays of matrices, and broadcast the matrix multiplication over them:

```
D = [rand(50, 60) for i in 1:4, j in 1:3]
E = [rand(60, 70) for i in 1:4, j in 1:3]
D .* E  # now you can use dot broadcasting!
```

That said, it's easy to make your own. I would make one change, though. Julia is column major, while numpy is "last dimension major", therefore you should let the matrices resided along the *first* two dimensions, not the last two.

First, I'll define an in-place method that multiplies into an array `C`, and then a non-in-place method that calls the in-place version (I'll skip dimension checking etc):

```
# In-place version, note the use of the @views macro, 
# which is essential to get in-place behaviour

using LinearAlgebra: mul!  # fast in-place matrix multiply

function batchmul!(C, A, B)
    for j in axes(A, 4), i in axes(A, 3)
        @views mul!(C[:, :, i, j], A[:, :, i, j], B[:, :, i, j])
    end
    return C
end

# The non-in-place version
function batchmul(A, B)
    T = promote_type(eltype(A), eltype(B))
    C = Array{T}(undef, size(A, 1), size(B)[2:end]...)
    return batchmul!(C, A, B)
end
```

You could also make it multi-threaded. <strike>On my computer 4 threads gives a 2.5x speedup (actually, for larger values of the last two dimensions, I get a 3.5x speedup)</strike> How much of a speedup you get depends on the sizes and shapes of the arrays involved:

```
function batchmul!(C, A, B)
    Threads.@threads for j in axes(A, 4)
        for i in axes(A, 3)
            @views mul!(C[:, :, i, j], A[:, :, i, j], B[:, :, i, j])
        end
    end
    return C
end
```

**Edit:** I noticed just now that you want general N-D, not just 4-D. Shouldn't be too hard to generalize, though. Anyway, all the more reason to go for arrays of matrices, where broadcasting will automatically work for all dimensionalities.

**Edit2:** Couldn't leave it, so here's one for the N-D case (there's still more to do, like handling non-1-based indexing (update: `axes` should fix this)):

```
function batchmul!(C, A, B)
    Threads.@threads for I in CartesianIndices(axes(A)[3:end])
        @views mul!(C[:, :, Tuple(I)...], A[:, :, Tuple(I)...], B[:, :, Tuple(I)...])
    end
    return C
end
```

Comment: I tend to prefer N-D arrays over array-of-arrays because they're easier to examine (for example `size` giving me a nice N-tuple), but in this case, the first solution does seem to be the most natural. Definitely gonna keep the general N-D solution around for reference though, thanks for the great answer!

Comment: For the 'matrix of arrays' solution, keep in mind that you can do it in-place with `mul!`: `for i in eachindex(C)
        mul!(C[i], A[i], B[i])
    end`   Dots won't work in-place, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For N=3 you are looking for `NNlib.batched_mul`. Notice that (as mentioned above) Julia's arrays are column-major, and thus it usually makes sense to regard the last not first index as running over the batch:

```
julia> using NNlib

julia> randn(4,3,100) ⊠ randn(3,2,100)
4×2×100 Array{Float64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
  0.9292     -0.223521
...
```

This is just a loop like `batchmul!(C, A, B)`, but it will also call the appropriate library function for GPU `CuArray`s.

It would not be very hard to extend this to more than 3 dimensions but someone would have to do it, and decide the rules. For the 3rd dimension, it behaves like broadcasting:

```
julia> randn(4,3,100) ⊠ randn(3,2) |> size
(4, 2, 100)

julia> randn(4,3,100) ⊠ randn(3,2,1) |> size
(4, 2, 100)

julia> try randn(4,3,100) ⊠ randn(3,2,2) catch e println(e) end
DimensionMismatch("batch size mismatch: A != B")
```